# login in cordova using phpmysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, cordova

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#insert").click(function(){
var email=$("#email").val();
var pass=$("#pass").val();
var dataString="email="+email+"&pass="+pass+"&insert=";
if($.trim(email).length>0 & $.trim(pass).length>0 )
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:"http://www.gaurav2444.5gbfree.com/login.php",
data: dataString,
crossDomain: true,
cache: false,
beforeSend: function(){ $("#insert").val('Connecting...');},
success: function(data){
if(data=="success")
{
alert("successful");
localStorage.login="true";
localStorage.email=email;
window.location.href = "index.html";
}
else if(data=="error")
{
alert("error"); 
$("#insert").val('Login');
}
}
});
}return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Php: 
login.php

```
 <?php
 include "db.php";
 if(isset($_POST['insert']))
   {
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $pass=$_POST['pass'];
 $sql = "SELECT * from `course_details` where `email`='$email' and `pass`='$pass'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
 {
 echo "success";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "error";
 }
 }
 ?>
```

db.php

```
 <?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","","","gaurav_sos") or die ("could not connect database");
 ?>
```

Program works well on xampp server but when php files and database is hosted it does not work on cordova app.
For example when following login id and password are entered in login page whwn files are in xampp server it works perfectly but when php files and database is hosted and php files are called from cordova app it does not give any result.
loginid:hero@d.com
password:123

Comment: Look at the server log!

Answer (score 1):

...And this is normal behavior for AJAX cross-domain requests - it **does not matther** that you manually set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

In order your code to work, you have to use some sort of a proxy, because [CORS policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) prohibit AJAX requests (because they violate [same-origin security policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)), this way you can make cross-domain AJAX requests to access resources **from third party websites** when it's not possible to enable CORS on target website i.e. when **you don't own** that website.

For example you can call first [PHP cross-domain proxy](https://github.com/softius/php-cross-domain-proxy) via AJAX, it then forwards your request to the real server.

A simple code modification using PHP cross-domain proxy library:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:"proxy.php", //This is where PHP cross-domain proxy is located
  csurl: "http://www.gaurav2444.5gbfree.com/login.php" //Your remote server
  });
```